# How do I sort list on all pagination pages?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have 2 html files index.html and list.html. The problem is when I load my list.html from index.html the sort filter a-z was just working on each page of pagination, not the whole list. So every time I add a new list (let's say li="AAA") it was just sort at the end of pagination page not on page 1.

index.html

```
<button onclick="javascript:showALL()">A</button>
<div id="pagination-container"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

list.html

```
<ul id="myUL">
<li><div class="list-item">SUPERMAN</div></li>
<li><div class="list-item">BATMAN</div></li>
<li><div class="list-item">AQUAMAN</div></li>
<li><div class="list-item">WONDERWOMAN</div></li>
</ul>
```

js

```
function showALL(){
$("#content").load("list.html", function() {
sortList();
})};

 function sortList() {
  var list, i, switching, b, shouldSwitch;
  list = document.getElementById("myUL");
  switching = true;
  /* Make a loop that will continue until
  no switching has been done: */
  while (switching) {
    // start by saying: no switching is done:
    switching = false;
    b = list.getElementsByTagName("li");
    // Loop through all list-items:
    for (i = 0; i < (b.length - 1); i++) {
      // start by saying there should be no switching:
      shouldSwitch = false;
      /* check if the next item should
      switch place with the current item: */
      if (b[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase() > b[i + 1].innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
        /* if next item is alphabetically
        lower than current item, mark as a switch
        and break the loop: */
        shouldSwitch = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      /* If a switch has been marked, make the switch
      and mark the switch as done: */
      b[i].parentNode.insertBefore(b[i + 1], b[i]);
      switching = true;
    }
  }
}

/*jquery.simplePagination.js - https://github.com/flaviusmatis/simplePagination.js*/

var items = $("#content .list-item");
var numItems = items.length;
var perPage = 5

items.slice(perPage).hide();

$('#pagination-container').pagination({
    items: numItems,
    itemsOnPage: perPage,
    prevText: "&laquo;",
    nextText: "&raquo;",
    onPageClick: function (pageNumber) {
        var showFrom = perPage * (pageNumber - 1);
        var showTo = showFrom + perPage;
        items.hide().slice(showFrom, showTo).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Can I ask a silly question? Why keep your list of items in a static HTML file rather than as a data array and use jQuery to create and insert your HTML rows? If your data is kept in a simple array, you can quickly sort it using a vanilla JavaScript `sort`.

Comment: I'm still learning into it. And the way I want to accomplish is like a set of division with image on it. it was like a <li><div></div</li> and there was image on it like gallery and per div is clickable that goes to other page.

Comment: Would probably be a good idea to use JSON for the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is every time you load that .html page in you get a new `<ul id='myUL'>` but your script is only able to process one of those.

you should never have duplicate ID's. This looks like some kind of class assignment, but you have 2 options. One is to change the .html file to use a classname instead of ID.

`<ul id="myUL">` becomes `<ul class="myUL">`

You function now needs to loop for each UL tag it finds and becomes this:

```
function sortList() {
  var lists, list, i, switching, b, shouldSwitch;
  lists = document.querySelectorAll(".myUL");
  lists.forEach(function(list) {
    switching = true;
    while (switching) {
      switching = false;
      b = list.getElementsByTagName("li");
      for (i = 0; i < (b.length - 1); i++) {
        shouldSwitch = false;
        if (b[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase() > b[i + 1].innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (shouldSwitch) {
        b[i].parentNode.insertBefore(b[i + 1], b[i]);
        switching = true;
      }
    }
});
}
```

The other approach is a bit more [Kabayashi Maru](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kobayashi_Maru) and personally i like it better. IN the end you'll have one big UL/LI list that grows every time you click the button

Change `<div id="content"></div>` into `<div id="content"><ul id="myUL"></ul></div>` and the contents of the other html file to

```
<li><div class="list-item">SUPERMAN</div></li>
<li><div class="list-item">BATMAN</div></li>
<li><div class="list-item">AQUAMAN</div></li>
<li><div class="list-item">WONDERWOMAN</div></li>
```

Then finally change this:

```
$("#myUL").load("list.html", function() {
   sortList();
})};
```

```js
function showALL() {
  /*$("#myUL").load("list.html", function() {
     sortList();
  })};*/

  $("#myUL").append('<li><div class="list-item">SUPERMAN</div></li><li><div class="list-item">BATMAN</div></li><li><div class="list-item">AQUAMAN</div></li><li><div class="list-item">WONDERWOMAN</div></li>');
  sortList();
  initPagination()
}

function sortList() {
  var lists, list, i, switching, b, shouldSwitch;
  lists = document.querySelectorAll("#myUL");
  lists.forEach(function(list) {
    switching = true;
    while (switching) {
      switching = false;
      b = list.getElementsByTagName("li");
      for (i = 0; i < (b.length - 1); i++) {
        shouldSwitch = false;
        if (b[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase() > b[i + 1].innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (shouldSwitch) {
        b[i].parentNode.insertBefore(b[i + 1], b[i]);
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  });
}

function initPagination() {
  var items = $("#content li:visible");
  var numItems = items.length;
  var perPage = 5

  items.slice(perPage).hide();

  $('#pagination-container').pagination({
    items: numItems,
    itemsOnPage: perPage,
    prevText: "&laquo;",
    nextText: "&raquo;",
    onPageClick: function(pageNumber) {
      var showFrom = perPage * (pageNumber - 1);
      var showTo = showFrom + perPage;
      items.hide().slice(showFrom, showTo).show();
    }
  });
}

function showOnly(letter) {
  if (!letter) $('#content li').show();
  else {
    $('#content li').each(function() {
      if ($(this).text().trim().toLowerCase().split('')[0] !== letter.toLowerCase()) $(this).hide();
      else $(this).show()
    })
  }
    initPagination()

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simplePagination.js/1.4/jquery.simplePagination.min.js" integrity="sha512-J4OD+6Nca5l8HwpKlxiZZ5iF79e9sgRGSf0GxLsL1W55HHdg48AEiKCXqvQCNtA1NOMOVrw15DXnVuPpBm2mPg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simplePagination.js/1.4/simplePagination.css" integrity="sha512-emkhkASXU1wKqnSDVZiYpSKjYEPP8RRG2lgIxDFVI4f/twjijBnDItdaRh7j+VRKFs4YzrAcV17JeFqX+3NVig==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<button onclick="showALL()">Load</button>
<div id="content">
  <ul id="myUL"></ul>
</div>
<div id="pagination-container"></div>
<button onclick="showOnly('A')">Show Only 'A'</button>
<button onclick="showOnly('B')">Show Only 'B'</button>
<button onclick="showOnly()">Reset</button>
```

Comment: I did this and I changed the load destination to <ul id="myUL">. The list on list.html becomes unstable and the sorting and pagination is not working. I'm thinking if im gonna do some other approach like showing all the list in one pages and by just filtering it by button for showing letter like showA, B, C, etc. and not use the pagination.

Comment: Sorry. It works. But the problem now is the pagination, it seems not showing and all the list was in all in one pages.

Comment: Ok, I added a snippet at the bottom of my answer. With the pagination, it looks like it needs to be run each time the list size grows, so I put it in a function. Take a look at the snippet and let me know if you have any questions

Comment: works like a charm! Thank you so much! I have also this one last problem on my project if its okay to ask you. Where can i dm you? it seems i can't post for 90mins here.

Comment: can you ask in comments here? it will eventually open a room.

Comment: Oh. Its related to this one. But let's say i have this another
<button onclick="javascript:showA()">A</button> that if you click it, it filter the list to show just the list with the first letter "A". same with the other button (B-Z)

Comment: ok, I updated the answer. There's a new function at the bottom and also updated this line: `var items = $("#content li:visible");` in pagination config